# Regularly self-joining table by next date

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, bigdata, database

What is best practice to regularly self-join a table by some table dependent value? We are regularly self-joining a table to see how an entity has changed between two discrete times. The current solution is primitive: for each row, there is a `prev_id` and `next_id` column which contain the respective rows one step forward/backward in time for that specific entity. This allows for easy self-joins without expensive subqueries.

Is there a better way to do this? Should we re-think the architecture? We currently have ~60k entities and 400mm observations.

Comment: Your method is fine.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. Do you have any advice on how to move the prev/next id process from batch to being atomic on insert? Right now we stream the inserts, and then batch the updates, sharded per entity. But I would like to have the proper prev/next ids at time of insert (inserts not guaranteed to come in sequential order).

Comment: Two inserts for the same entity arrive out of order?  Can you recognize an out-of-order insert and hand it off for batch processing, while doing the in-order ones en-masse?

Comment: No, since they are just timestamped observations we have no way of knowing if the arrive in the task queue out of order.